# What causes a sudden and narrow V-shape patterns in stock price?

Tags: stocks

I have seen these a few times, usually in after-hours activity. For example, the one shown in the below image.

Is it a pre-scheduled (like 105b kind of) *Sell @ $115 of better order* hitting the market? or something else?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked other sources of data to see if they show the same artifact? Most likely a glitch in the data.

Comment: With illiquid stocks, sometimes you can see a sharp V or inverted V shape spike or drop when the bid/ask spread widens dramatically during after hours. However, not  $12 point drop in AAPL that's depicted in the graph.  It's almost a certainty that you're looking at bad data.

Comment: Just one point, it's not really a "V", that's nothing more than the javascript in the web page trying to draw one single oddball data point at that scale.  (It is inconceivable / incoherent that that trades "followed two straight lines" like that, just to be clear.)  Indeed on other web sites it wont be drawn with a "V", it will be sort of a square U, a strange "X" down there, or whatever.  the "V" per se has no reality (it would be like asking "why is it green" you know?!)